# PHP emails are not received on Yahoo account

Tags: html, email

We have developed a web app using PHP 5.0 and MySQL 5.0. It runs on Apache on a Linux Redhat. It has a feature by which, the app sends email to the user's registered email address using mail() function. It works fine for GMail or Hotmail email account. It is not working for Yahoo or Rediffmail email account.

Any idea of where to start debugging this? Thank you.

Comment: This is email client related, before any answer is possible - we will need the content of your email and some server settings at least. As this problem can have **alot** of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look at a class like Swiftmailer(.org) or PHPmailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com) as they give better headers and are more likely to get the mail out of the junkbox.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few settings with could cause such problems.

Are there wrong SPF entries for the domain or does the reverse lookup of your sender ip not point to the sender name?